# Check ng-model object length

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Add class if ng-models has length dosnt work

```
<input id="Id{{regItem.name}}" ng-model='registrationData[regItem.name]'/>
<label for="Id{{regItem.name}}" ng-class="{focused : registrationData[regItem.name].length)}"
```

Comment: is `registrationData` initiated to anything?

Comment: `ng-class="{ registrationData[regItem.name].length > 0? 'focused': ' '}"` give it a try!

Comment: @jusopi yes is it

Comment: @AliBaig doesnt work

Comment: Is there any error or it just doesn't add the class?

Comment: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined @AliBaig

Comment: You would be doing some small mistake..there is extra round bracket in your label html..  I created the jsfiddle it works there - https://jsfiddle.net/a53jy25d/

Comment: @N.K in this case its work        http://prntscr.com/e2trfh
 But in this way doesnt      http://prntscr.com/e2tshi

Comment: What about it isn't working? Are you talking about the `<input>` placeholder text overlapping with the input's value? Also what does `registrationData` and `regItem.name` look like? If your using a <form> can you instead do something like `ng-model="registrationData.someProperty"` instead of bracket notation?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky my destination is make input like material design input , floating labels ,,on input focus/and not empty state label must change position , but in my case i cant detect inputs not empty state

Comment: Try putting `{{registrationData[regItem.name]}}` and `{{registrationData[regItem.name].length > 0}}` and `{{regItem.name}}` somewhere in the template beside the input and determine if that ng-model property is even being set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try

```
ng-class="registrationData[regItem.name] && registrationData[regItem.name].length > 0? 'focused': ''"
```

But make sure `regItem.name` exists on `registrationData` object. I have added a simple [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/tfU80jkHB13f95gjuKY3) for you to play around! It updates the color of a div once you enter something in the textbox.

Comment: Try removing the braces with a ternary express like in this within angular templates. `ng-class="registrationData[regItem.name] && registrationData[regItem.name].length > 0 ? 'focused': ''"`

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Correct!

Comment: @AroTonoyan See `https://plnkr.co/edit/bEirH6ouk37ECyZe3Pkf` and check how its implemented!

Comment: Maybe something like this to match the two different inputs, forked from yours @AliBaig https://plnkr.co/edit/H1SHKmp0w9Tas7mFCwvf?p=preview